# If $F$ is algebraically closed and $tr.d.F/K$ is finite, then every $K$-monomorphism $F \rightarrow F$ is an automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If $F$ is algebraically closed and $tr.d.F/K$ is finite, then every $K$-monomorphism $F \rightarrow F$ is an automorphism

First, suppose that a transcendence base of $F$ over $K$ is $\{s\}$. Then every $K$-monomorphism are uniquely determined by the value at $s$.

Consider the $K$-monomorphism $\sigma$ with $\sigma(s)=s^n$ where $n$ is an integer. Since $F$ is algebraically closed, there exists a root of the equation $x^n=s$. Let's call it $u$. Then $$\sigma(u)^n=\sigma(u^n)=\sigma(s)=s^n$$ Therefore, $\sigma(u)=s$. I tried to use this idea to show the general case. But what about the case $\sigma(s)=s^5+s+1$? I cannot use the same idea.

It is really hard to me. I need your help. Thanks in advance.

Edit :

Just the case $n=p$ and $chatK=p$, we get $(\sigma(u)-s)^p=\sigma(u)^n-s^p=0$

Comment: $\sigma(u)^n=s^n$ does not imply $\sigma(u)=s$.

Comment: @Hagen Oops. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to be too explicit when you're trying to understand the task for *particular* monomorphisms one at a time.

Instead, suppose $(s_1,\ldots,s_k)$ is a transcendence basis for $F/K$, and consider the field $L$ of all elements of $F$ that are algebraic over $K(\sigma(s_1),\ldots,\sigma(s_k))$.

Because $\sigma$ is a monomorphism, any nontrivial algebraic relation between the $\sigma(s_i)$s will also be an algebraic relation between the $s_i$s, and we're assuming there is none. So the $\sigma(s_i)$s are algebraically independent.

If $L\ne F$ then the $\sigma(s_i)$s can be extended to an algebraically independent set in $F/K$ with *more* than $k$ elements, which contradicts $k$ being the transcendence degree. So $L=F$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Let $u \in F - K(\sigma(s_{1}),...,\sigma(s_{k}))$. Since $u$ is algebraic over $K(\sigma(s_{1}),...,\sigma(s_{k}))$, there exists a minimal polynomial $f(x) \in K(\sigma(s_{1}),...,\sigma(s_{k}))[x]$ of $u$. Since $F$ is algebraically closed, there exist all roots $\{v_{1},...,v_{t}=u \} \in F$. Since $\sigma$ is monomorphism and $\sigma$ sends root to root, we get $\sigma(v_{l})=u$ for some $l$. Thanks!

Comment: @Guillermo: Yes, except I think you should be more explicit about pulling $f$ back from $K(\sigma(s_1),\ldots,\sigma(s_k))[x]$ to $\sigma^{-1}(f)\in K(s_1,\ldots,s_k)[x]$ before you appeal to the algebraic closedness to find its roots.